# JayData orderBy function produce strange result

Tags: web-sql, jaydata

I have table in `websql` to get data from that i am using `JayData` and write this

```
_context.FoodLog.include("FoodItem").orderByDescending("it.TotalCalories").toArray().then(function(foodLogs)
{
    $scope.$apply(function ()
    {
        try
        {
            for(var i=0; i<foodLogs.length; i++)
            {
                console.log(foodLogs[i].TotalCalories);                             
            }
        }
        catch(error)
        {
            console.log("Inner Try  "+error);
        }
    })
});
```

in console the result is

```
738.00
31.56           // why this 31.50 comes before 127.91 and 101.81
127.91
101.81
10.00
10.00
```

but it shows that result-set in not in specific order

**Update**
Table Structure

```
$data.Entity.extend('SpookyHealthAppModel.FoodLog', {
'FoodLogID': { 'key':true,'type':'Edm.Int32','nullable':false,'computed':true },
'Quantity': { 'type':'Edm.String','maxLength':5 },
'TotalCalories': { 'type':'Edm.String','maxLength':10 },
'DateTime': { 'type':'Edm.DateTime' },
'ImageCol': { 'type':'Edm.String','maxLength':50 },
'Sync': { 'type':'Edm.Boolean' },
'FoodItem': { 'type':'SpookyHealthAppModel.FoodItem','required':true,'inverseProperty':'FoodLog' },
'User': { 'type':'SpookyHealthAppModel.User','required':true,'inverseProperty':'FoodLog' }
});
```

Comment: @Vote-Downer
Please specify the reason or mistake or else it would me really helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my problem :)
According to my table structure my query works fine
Because the field on which I put `order by` clause has `String DataType` and result is in order according to strings if I want result in numerical order change this line

```
'TotalCalories': { 'type':'Edm.String','maxLength':10 },
```

into this

```
'TotalCalories': { 'type':'Edm.Int32'}, // No need to define length now if you want in float then define float instead of int
```